# Is there a way to embed/insert a clipart image (from the left panel) into a editable text area?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

For example, I want to be able to drag a General Rectangle or a UML Class 1 object and edit the text, then insert a clipart image from the "Clipart / Computer" section into the object.

I know I can drag the clipart image on top of the object, but if I tried to auto re-arrange the layout I'd have to fix all the image positions which could take time.

Is there a way to insert clipart images into these objects that I don't know about?  Or a way to reference these images by URL, since that's the only way I can seem to embed images right now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google picker (4th icon from right on toolbar) to add images, as shown in [this video](http://youtu.be/s_61rQ-eOBk).

Comment: Thanks, that works for the Rectangle.. for the UML Class 1 object, I copied the URL from the Clipart's Style URL to insert the image and it works for me.  In the video it's mentioned that the URL is for a cached image so I hope that the image will always be there in the future?

Comment: Yes, these are persistence image URLs.